# SQL Server Management Studio requiring full table path

Tags: sql, sql-server

Yesterday, in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) (v17.6) I could write and execute:

```
select * from MyTable;
```

Today, I now must write:

```
Select * from myDbName.dbo.MyTable;
```

However, the old syntax will recognize that the table is there and pull back the headers, but no content.  Also, the intellisense with the older syntax.

Yet, in my VB code, I can still use the initial statement shown above.

Why? And, how do I change it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely connected to another database on the instance. This commonly happens when the default database for the login isn't set to something explicitly. It defaults the the master database. You'll need to change it in the drop down for intellisense to pick up your table names, and for you to not have to fully qualify the `server.database.schema.table`.

[image: SSMS]

Also, in the bottom right of your query window, make sure the query window which you are executing your query from is actually connected to the correct database. Since you aren't getting results back, I'd bet that you are also not connected to the correct database when you run your query, but an older or developmental database (where the data is different).

Comment: No worries @TripIves, it's the little things that will get ya!